# Private Accessors in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, private-members

as far as I know Visual Studio 2012 will not support Private Accessors. Can you give me some infos on possible alternatives? PrivateObject.Invoke() is not the best solution for me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Mark your members as "internal" and use the InternalsVisibleTo attribute. Simple to use and no type safety issues.

Comment: I've done it this way before the Privat eAccessors were introduced. Thanx!

Comment: I find it interesting that many of the .NET Framework assemblies show InternalsVisibleTo attributes in Reflector.

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with the Fakes framework. You can't shim internal classes, even with InternalsVisibleTo set correctly. PrivateObject.Invoke isn't really an option, either. Sadly, in removing support for accessors, they removed the one way that would work for shimming an internal class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this posting [Home-made Private Accessor for Visual Studio 2012+](http://blog.instance-factory.com/?p=810) will help you creating your own Private Accessor.

Regards,

Stefan

Comment: Found a hint to the command line tool Publicize.exe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569957%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) by Axel Mayer in MSDN forum (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/015e1ac7-acf3-4d83-ae0c-734c8957cde4/how-to-create-private-accessors-in-vs-2012?forum=vsunittest). 
Found it in VS 2012 and VS 2013 (Ultimate). Worked for .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5, but not for a Windows Store app. Look at %Program Files (x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE.

The tool creates a dll that can be used by your unit test project. Better than writing the accessors yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I started using the *Dynamic Private Accessor* feature that is part of the nuget package [Chaining Assertion for MSTest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChainingAssertion/) and I am rather happy with it. One looses strong typing but at least the syntax is still readable.
This works with the *dynamic* feature. There are also packages for other testing frameworks.
Testing code looks like this:

```
var target = CreateMyObjectUnderTest();
dynamic dynamicTarget = target.AsDynamic();
Assert.AreEqual("abc", dynamicTarget.MyPrivateProperty);
Assert.AreEqual("xyz", dynamicTarget.PrivateMethod(123));
```