# Replacements for private accessors in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I startet to migrate a Testproject from VS2010 to 2012. 
Now I see that the private accessors are not supported anymore.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361647/private-accessors-in-visual-studio-2012) , but is that the only way to fix that?
I don't want to declare the private methods as internal... :-(

Comment: Testing private methods is not a good way to test ...

Comment: I know, but in the first step I must run the tests against it. After that I can refactor that...

Comment: Would using [`PrivateObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) directly help?

Comment: Hi, thx alot for your responses. I decided to use the PrivateObject. That is the best way to sole my "problem" :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that in your case using using PrivateObjects will help you. To view how to use them, you can view this link: http://akurniaga.wordpress.com/tag/unit-test-privateobject-visual-studio/ . Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the usage of PrivateObject by a generic base class like shown by the posting [Home-made Private Accessor for Visual Studio 2012+](http://blog.instance-factory.com/?p=810) might ease and simplify its usage.

Regards,

Stefan